# acceder a funciones de una variable en un constructor js

Tags: javascript

quiero accerder a la variable ctx la cual esta localizada en el constructor de mi juego y en la funcion bucle la cual accede a ella para limpiar el canvas me sale el error "main.js:191 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearRect' of undefined"
codigo->

```
class JuegoSnake {
   constructor() {
    this.comidas = [];
    this.canv = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.puntuacion = 0;
    this.ctx = this.canv.getContext("2d");
    this.scl = 40;
    this.canv.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canv.height = Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 1);
    this.serpiente = new snake();
    this.comidas.push(new comida(this.scl));

}


draw() {

    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canv.width, this.canv.height);
    drawFondo(this.ctx);
       }
```

Comment: Dónde y cómo estás llamando el método `draw()`?

Comment: var juego=new JuegoSnake(); setInterval(juego.draw,40); ya que no puedo llamar un metodo en el contructor de la propia clase que me cree el intervalo lo hago asi :(

Comment: intenta poner console.log(this.canv) antes de llamar a clearRect a ver que sucede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas draw estas fuera del contexto del constructor, es decir estas en otro tiempo y momento donde el this.ctx no existe.  Para corregir esto puedes agregar esto a tu clase

```
class JuegoSnake {
   constructor() {
    this.comidas = [];
// ...
    this.comidas.push(new comida(this.scl));

    // le pasamos el contexto actual de la clase
    this.draw = this.draw.bind(this);
   }

   draw(){
      console.log(this.ctx) // ahora tendra lo que necesitas
   }
}
```

Agregando el bind anexamos el contexto actual de la clase y ya puedes invocarla :D como esperabas.

Más información del contexto de *this* en:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this

Comment: solucionado, pero no termino de entenderlo 100%, el resultado de mi codigo es crear el juego Snake, cuando creo la clase serpiente me permite acceder a sus coordenadas x e y (desde el propio objeto: serpiente.this.x)con this sin ningun problema, ¿porque al crear la clase juego y querer acceder a su variable desde una funcion interna d ela propia clase tengo que hacer esto?Gracias¡

Comment: Son cosas del contexto en javascript para el paradigma de orientado a objetos, es un poco largo de explicar, pero aqui lo puedes ver (En inglés) https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb